# Hide a QueryString parameters, how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a url: like this one: ***`http://www.example/about/49`***.
I want it to be seen as ***`http://www.example/about/`***, but I must have this parameters passed as *`QueryString`* parameters.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Use Session Variables to store what you want, and bind it to a viewstate to allow it to work for every unique user.

Comment: Not possible, you want to pass it in query string, and dont want to show it. this isnt possible, or what you can do is redirect to http;//www.example/about/49 then fetch the value 49, store it in session variable, then redirect to http://www.example/about/49. this is almost nonsense idea,, but thats the only way, and no one would recommend this, not either me.

Comment: using querystring i think you coudn't

Comment: @SonerGönül no I didn't know where to start, otherwise I didn't been asking here.

Comment: I aggree with @QasimJavaidKhan, If you hide the parameter, then controller cant read parameters from querystring, so This method will not be "HTTPGET" . So there will be a logic problem.

Comment: Then make it simple. store your id = 49 in a session variable and redirect to page example/about... that would work. or else tell us the reason why you dont want to show in the query string or why you only want to pass it in query string?

Comment: Do you like it 
@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "Controller", new { QParameterName=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(QuerystringValue) })

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with session variables; it's easy to have multiple pages opened which are all using the same session and end up mixing the values.

It would be better to use `TempData`, which only allows the value to be used once (removed on first access). However, this implies the value will be used almost immediately.

You can also write a cookie with the desired value, intercept the request (ASP.Net provides a variety of ways of doing this, such as the `BeginRequest` event), and internally process the URL as though it contained the value.

Of course, you then must cleanup the cookie (which will have the same problem as a Session-based solution). Remember that a cookie is more vulnerable to tampering on the client.

Personally, I think any of these approaches are far more trouble than they are worth. "[Hackable URLs](http://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/990/)" (such as those which contain a potentially meaningful ID) are usually a *good* thing.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this (Which works REALLY well, thanks to the help of the SO Community)

Create a class called `SiteSession.cs`

Input the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for SiteSession
/// </summary>
public class SiteSession
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The _site session
    /// </summary>
    private const string _siteSession = "__SiteSession__";


    /// <summary>
    /// Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="SiteSession" /> class from being created.
    /// </summary>
    private SiteSession()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current Session
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current.</value>
    public static SiteSession Current
    {
        get
        {
            SiteSession session = new SiteSession();
            try
            {
                session = HttpContext.Current.Session[_siteSession] as SiteSession;
            }
            catch(NullReferenceException asp)
            {

            }

            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new SiteSession();
                HttpContext.Current.Session[_siteSession] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }

    //Session properties
    public int PageNumber {get;set;}

}
```

You can put anything in the `Session Properties`, just make sure its public.

Then, set it by:

`SiteSession.Current.PageNumber = 42`

And call it with

`int whatever = SiteSession.Current.PageNumber`

Comment: The whole point was to stay out of session and hidden and this stuff.
I thought to use URL Rewriter or something in this area.

Comment: You cannot hide `QueryString`, or anything else in the URL input. Its simply against the Client Browser rules. The only thing you can hide is in the web page. If you really dont want to use Sessions, then you're in for a hard time.